# How to create a column which is a shifted version of another column, disregarding duplicates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, shift, cumsum

I have a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8],
})
```

> ```
>     a
> 0   1
> 1   2
> 2   3
> 3   3
> 4   3
> 5   4
> 6   4
> 7   5
> 8   5
> 9   5
> 10  6
> 11  7
> 12  8
> ```

And i need to create `b` which is a "shift" of `a` such that every entry in b will be the closest entry in a which is not a duplicate, and is below that entry.

Required output:

> ```
>     a  b
> 0   1  2
> 1   2  3
> 2   3  4
> 3   3  4
> 4   3  4
> 5   4  5
> 6   4  5
> 7   5  6
> 8   5  6
> 9   5  6
> 10  6  7
> 11  7  8
> 12  8  nan
> ```

---

Looks like some sort of a combination of `cumsum`, `shift`, `mask`, but I can't quite put them together. Maybe it's something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].where(~df['a'].duplicated(keep='first')).bfill().shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
    a    b
0   1  2.0
1   2  3.0
2   3  4.0
3   3  4.0
4   3  4.0
5   4  5.0
6   4  5.0
7   5  6.0
8   5  6.0
9   5  6.0
10  6  7.0
11  7  8.0
12  8  NaN
```

Details:

My approach is to find the duplicate values in `a` then mask and bfill with next unmasked value then shift the series `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `map` on the unique value:

```
s = df['a'].drop_duplicates()

df['b'] = df['a'].map(pd.Series(s.shift(-1).values,s))
```

Output:

```
    a    b
0   1  2.0
1   2  3.0
2   3  4.0
3   3  4.0
4   3  4.0
5   4  5.0
6   4  5.0
7   5  6.0
8   5  6.0
9   5  6.0
10  6  7.0
11  7  8.0
12  8  NaN
```

Comment: why did you edit? what was wrong with the previous answer?

Comment: @Gulzar `ffill` was filling the last `NaN` with `8` in the expected output.

Comment: I chose the other answer because it didn't require construction of a new series. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

If just based on the sample data you showed

```
df['b'] = (df['a'].add(1)).where(df['a'].add(1).isin(df['a']))
df
Out[404]: 
    a    b
0   1  2.0
1   2  3.0
2   3  4.0
3   3  4.0
4   3  4.0
5   4  5.0
6   4  5.0
7   5  6.0
8   5  6.0
9   5  6.0
10  6  7.0
11  7  8.0
12  8  NaN
```

If not

```
df['b'] = df.a.map(dict(zip(df.a.unique()[:-1],df.a.unique()[1:])))
```

Comment: I tried to give random simple sample data off of my head. The real data is much more complex and random

Comment: @Gulzar check the if not ~